# How can I get the current build flavor?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, tfsbuild

What variable can I use to get the current build flavour? i.e. Release or Debug

I'm trying to copy files which exist in release or debug folders, so I need to know which ones are currently beign created i.e am I in Release or Debug.

TF2010 scripts gave me access through ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild properties which I used to set in my script but these no longer evaluate.

e.g.

```
<Message Text="Move all Assemblies from $(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild) to $(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\bin\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild) "></Message>
```

Answer (score 2):

From your <Message> tag in the example it looks like you are working inside an MSBuild project file.  For that use the **$(Configuration)** variable.

If you are inside a projects post build event, use **$(ConfigurationName)**

Update:
The $(Configuration) comes from your .sln and project (.csproj or .vbproj) files.  The .sln includes different solution configurations which govern project configurations.  So it is possible to have one project build with a 'Debug' configuration and another project build with a 'Release' configuration as part of the same solution build.

Comment: $(Configuration) definitely gives me Release or Debug. I think that will work. My messages are showing the the $(Configuration) and %(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild) differ sometimes however! any ideas which one to trust? I'll know more when the build eventually completes.

Comment: I assume that $((ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild) comes from the TFS xaml based build system.  I have very limited experience with that.  So I am not real sure why MSBuild's $(Configuration) would get out of synch with TFS build.